# How can I call the api in template

Tags: html, django, api, django-rest-framework, microservices

How can I call the rest api in django template.I want to design the microservices and just got thinking about calling a api in the front end.How could I achieve this.

Usually when I work in monolithic I directly call it from the database in the html but not case in microservices part.

Comment: Django is a MVT framework. i.e. Model, View, Template. All the business logic should be written in View. Template should not  be used for this. Here is a good resource for Implementing microservices. [Implementing Microservices on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/microservices-on-aws/microservices-on-aws.html). For more info on better software development, [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) is a good resource.

Comment: I'm designing a microservices Django application where I'm creating two applications individually which communicate each other to get the data and there is a front end part where I will link those two applications. In such a case how could i able to render it to the template ?Do i need to get the api into the views n then render it to the template.Is there any way that i can achieve it?

Comment: yes you have to call API from view and then render in template... from template its not a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call Django API from your template then you can use AJAX. You can get a reference from the below code and add it to your HTML templete

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
    dataType:"json",
  url: 'https//yourendpoint/api/',
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('data: ', data);
    //your logic
  }
});
</script>
```

For more detail, you can check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp). You can implement it using jquery or js.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your core logic so that you can call from your view the same logic you call from your API. To illustrate this an example,

*models.py*

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
   attr_1 = ...
   attr_2 = ...

   def add_x_y(self, x, y):
      return x + y
```

Since your logic lives in the model which is the base of MVT structure, then you can use the defined logic anywhere you like. for example

*api/views.py*

```
def some_api_function():
   x = 1
   y = 3
   result = {'result': MyModel.add_x_y(x,y)}
   return json_response(result)
```

*views.py*

```
def some_template_function():
   x = 1
   y = 3
   result = {'result': MyModel.add_x_y(x,y)}
   return render_to_response(tempalate.html, {'result': result})
```

When you separate your logic to the bottom level of your application you can re-use in your api view, normal view and any other service functions.

Please disregard the syntax, this is just for example use.